# Can we have two different session name for normal user and admin user?

Tags: php

This is for normal user.

```
if($pass) {
            /*password is correct*/
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
}
```

I have different login page for admin, would this work.

```
if($pass) {
            /*password is correct*/
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['admin_username'] = $username;
}
```

There is a normal dashboard and admin dashboard. So if the session is admin_username then the user should be redirected to admin dashboard and if the session is username then the user should be directed to normal dashboard. Is this method prone to any error or conflict ?

I could also have one session name check if session is not empty and if $_SESSION['username'] equals username of admin redirect to admin dashboard else its normal user.

Which approach is better ?

Comment: THe second option you yourself named is what usually is done.

Comment: That has nothing to do with session name—it's just a custom variable. This design suggests you should be able to be signed in with two users at the same time as long as they belong to different types. Do you really intend that?

Answer (score 2):

I would advise you to split the username from the role.
You can add a separate session parameter with admin indicator

```
if($pass) {
    /*password is correct*/
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['isAdmin'] = true;
}
```

But you should keep in mind that when you ever want to add a third role, you should save the role in the session.

```
if($pass) {
    /*password is correct*/
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['role'] = "Admin"; // Or "Moderator" or  "User"
}
```